# Minimal required to control std::map order

Tags: c++, sorting, stdmap

I know that `std::map` is by nature an ordered map, but I wonder:

If I have classes `A` and `B` and I create a `std::map<A, B> myMap;`, what is the minimal needed to create my own order?

Is overloading `A::operator <(const A&)` enough?

Or do I have to make my own iterator?

Comment: Elements are sorted strictly by their keys. The value of `myMap[a1]` doesn't come into play at all. Maybe you want a `std::set` of your own pair type, which you can then sort whichever way you want taking both elements into consideration.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes there is a problem in what I wrote. I'm editing.

Comment: yes, you just have to write the operator < for class A. Class B is just supplying content and does not take part in the comparison.